# How come nobody in the police found the relation between Brian Moser and Dexter?

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

In the final episode of Season 1 of Dexter, Dexter finds out the truth about Brian Moser.

It is mentioned during the season that Dexter adoptive father removed any evidence of what happened when his mother was murdered, but it wasn't mentioned that he removed all evidence about the real identity of Brian.

So how come Dexter's team didn't find the truth, and thought Brian Moser is not related to him?

I still did not watch any other season, so would like to know if this is explained within the scope of season 1.

Comment: Did you watch the rest of the show, though? Cause I think this is explained in season 4.

Comment: @Walt nope. Added the info to the question. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dexter tells us that he is adopted - S1 E1
Dexter recovers the repressed memory of his mother's murder - S1 E10
Dexter is directed by the ice truck killer to a newspaper detailing their mother's death. He learns that she was involved in criminal activity that led to her death. His name is suppressed from the article. - S1 E11
It can be surmised at this point that information about Dexter's biological family would have been supressed for his own protection. It is later confirmed in the series that Harry had suppressed the information and only adopted Dexter alone, fearing that the older brother was already damaged goods.

Comment: "information about Dexter's biological family" - well, thought he only erased information about the murder, not the whole family information. Thanks! :)